# Unable to unlink library with react-native unlink

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-linking

**1.** I unlinked a library because I am using [React Native >v0.59](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60) that links libraries automatically.

```
(base) Somedude@Programmers-Machine-4:~/CrossPlatformProjects/ReactNative/someapp$ react-native unlink @react-native-community/async-storage
    info Unlinking "@react-native-community/async-storage" iOS dependency
    info iOS module "@react-native-community/async-storage" has been successfully unlinked
    info Unlinking "@react-native-community/async-storage" Android dependency
    info Android module "@react-native-community/async-storage" has been successfully unlinked
    (base) Somedude@Programmers-Machine-4:~/CrossPlatformProjects/ReactNative/spotsrn$ react-native run-android
```

**2.** Above it shows that the library has been successfully unlinked, but then when I try to build for android it claims the library is linked:

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - @react-native-community/async-storage (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/async-storage")
  - react-native-fbsdk (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-fbsdk")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
```

This has happened to other packages as well and I don't think it is related to the `react-native-community/async-storage` library. Is there a process to reset/resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the iOS and android folder then run

```
react-native eject
```

Then build

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: I am not using expo `react-native eject` is not available.